# Axon Framework : Table tokenentry doesn't exist

Tags: cqrs, axon

I'm new in development with Axon Framework. My problem is when I run my microservice (a client connecting to Axon Server), this error message

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'banking2.**tokenentry**' doesn't exist
```

is displayed in console and my microservie fails to start!

Answer (score 1):

It pretty much depends how you have configured your project and how you want to setup the tables.

A common approach for enterprises is to have scripts (in form of migrations) that will run and create the tables. If that is the case, you have to provide your own scripts to create it.

If you are using Hibernate for instance, you can set the `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` property to ask it to create it (among other options, better check their docs).